# Compute residues for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin x}{1+x^4}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I am trying to compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin x}{1+x^4}dx$$

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644893/integrate-int-0-infty-fracx-sinx1-x4-dx), but the asker and answerer skip over the calculation of the residues.

Define the curve $\gamma$ to be the semicircle in the top half plane with radius $R$ and straight edge on the real axis from $-R$ to $R$.

Then by the residue theorem and Jordan's lemma, taking $R \to \infty$, I know that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z e^{iz}}{1+z^4}dz = \oint_{\gamma} \frac{ze^{iz}}{1+z^4} dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{\alpha \text{ roots of } 1+z^4, \Im(\alpha)>0} \text{Res}\left(\frac{z e^{iz}}{1+z^4}, \alpha \right)$$

The relevant roots are $\alpha=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}, e^{\frac{3 \pi i}{4}}$.

How can I go about calculating these residues? I know that it's the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ the Laurent series at $\alpha$, or also $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\partial D(\alpha, r)} \frac{z e^{iz}}{1+z^4} dz$. I'm struggling to calculate either of these. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^4+1=(z-w_1)\cdots(z-w_4)$, where $w_j=e^{2\pi ij/4}$, for $j=1, 2,3,4$. You are interested in $w_1$ and $w_3$. Since they are poles of order $1$ you calculate the residues as $$\lim_{z\to w_1}(z-w_1) \frac{ze^{iz}}{1+z^4}, $$ and same for $w_3$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n$-th order pole at $z=a$, the general residue formula is:

$$Res(f, a)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to a}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}((z-a)^nf(z))$$

For simple pole, $n=1$, we get

$$Res(f, a)=\lim_{z\to a}~(z-a)f(z)$$

Comment: I've accepted Guillermo García Sáez's answer since it was first, but this is really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\res}{\operatorname{Res}}$For **simple** poles it is easier to use the following approach. For higher order poles, the use of *Taylor* and *Laurent* expansions dramatically simplifies the procedure. The limit formula is correct but generally unwieldy.

> Task: evaluate $\res(f;\zeta)$ where $f$ is meromorphic with a simple pole at $\zeta$.

Identify the "problematic" part of $f$ and express $f=h/g$ where $h$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $\zeta$ and $g$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of, and has a simple zero at, $\zeta$. Then quite simply: $$\res(f;\zeta)=h(\zeta)/g'(\zeta)$$

Example:

> Evaluate: $$\res\left(z\mapsto\frac{ze^{iz}}{1+z^4};e^{\pi i/4}\right)$$

I just bring out the $ze^{iz}$ term as it is analytic at the given point, and $1+z^4$ has a simple zero at $e^{\pi i/4}$ and derivative $4z^3$ so: $$\res=\frac{(e^{\pi i/4})e^{ie^{\pi i/4}}}{4e^{3\pi i/4}}=\frac{1}{4i}\exp(-2^{-1/2})\exp(i2^{-1/2})$$The other residue is easily evaluated with the same method to be: $$-\frac{1}{4i}\exp(-2^{-1/2})\exp(-i2^{-1/2})$$In sum we get: $$\frac{1}{2e^{1/\sqrt{2}}}\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$So that: $$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{x\cdot\sin x}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{e^{1/\sqrt{2}}}\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$